# Ionic 3 requires a peer

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this project made in ionic 3 I want to try to start it but these dependencies are not letting me install someone knows about this type of problem

I tried to perform an npm install

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/barcode-scanner@3.14.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/camera@3.14.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/facebook@3.14.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file@3.12.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file-transfer@4.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/geolocation@3.14.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/in-app-browser@3.11.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/status-bar@3.12.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/transfer@3.12.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN com.app.facebooklogin@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN com.app.facebooklogin@1.0.0 No license field.

audited 516 packages in 1.83s
found 75 vulnerabilities (29 low, 17 moderate, 29 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

[image]

this is where I have my dependencies installed in the respective project, there is some version of angular cli that seems to be that they are not compatible

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "name": "com.app.facebooklogin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "app",
  "dependencies": {
    "@ionic-native/barcode-scanner": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^4.2.1",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.14.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.11.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.12.1",
    "com.ionic.keyboard": "https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git",
    "cordova-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-compat": "^1.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.1",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^4.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.6.3",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^1.7.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^2.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.5.6",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-minify-css": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "2.0.4",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "git+https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugins-keyboard.git",
    "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": "^6.0.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "^1.3.3",
    "gulp-util": "^2.2.14",
    "shelljs": "^0.3.0"
  },
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "com.ionic.keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "com.ionic.keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " ",
        "PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-file-transfer": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GEOLOCATION_USAGE_DESCRIPTION": " "
      },
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "xxxxx",
        "APP_NAME": "App"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your package.json

Comment: it was already updated

Comment: angular packages are completely missing under the dev dependencies in package.json

Answer (score 0):

Install angular packages for ionic using the below command. This should add the missing dependencies to your package.json

```
npm install ionic-angular@latest --save
```